# Where is the users password actually updated in Devise::PasswordsController?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, sql-update

I am quite new to rails Device gem. and Trying to understand how it work.

In my project, there is Devise::PasswordsController.

```
  def update
    self.resource = resource_class.reset_password_by_token(resource_params)
    yield resource if block_given?

    if resource.errors.empty?
      resource.unlock_access! if unlockable?(resource)
      if Devise.sign_in_after_reset_password
        flash_message = resource.active_for_authentication? ? :updated : :updated_not_active
        set_flash_message!(:notice, flash_message)
        resource.after_database_authentication
        sign_in(resource_name, resource)
      else
        set_flash_message!(:notice, :updated_not_active)
      end
      respond_with resource, location: after_resetting_password_path_for(resource)
    else
      set_minimum_password_length
      respond_with resource
    end
  end
```

This will update new password to database.

In my server log. I can see `UPDATE` SQL query executed.

```
UPDATE `users` SET `reset_password_sent_at` = NULL, `encrypted_password` = 'somevalue......', `reset_password_token` = NULL, `updated_at` = '2020-xx-xx xx:xx:xx' WHERE `users`.`id` = xxx
```

but,

***Why Can't I find any ruby code equivalent to this?*** as in `resource.update` things like that.

Sorry if my question is doesn't make sense. And if so, please correct my misunderstanding.

***Where can I find the function that executes SQL?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual update is happening in [Devise::Models::Recoverable#reset_password](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/29943a26e61d68198666c59e07457dba3c75f581/lib/devise/models/recoverable.rb#L37) which is called by [#reset_password_by_token](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/29943a26e61d68198666c59e07457dba3c75f581/lib/devise/models/recoverable.rb#L145).

```
# Update password saving the record and clearing token. Returns true if
# the passwords are valid and the record was saved, false otherwise.
def reset_password(new_password, new_password_confirmation)
  if new_password.present?
    self.password = new_password
    self.password_confirmation = new_password_confirmation
    save
  else
    errors.add(:password, :blank)
    false
  end
end
```

Comment: The devise code is pretty dense and hard to follow due to the fact that its needs to be so flexible and make so few assumptions and the huge scope of the project. Everything is also modular to a really high degree so there are a lot more steps then in "bespoke" code.